# Wayland and display standby

Tags: wayland, standby

I am new to wayland and developing a wayland client application that play videos. The problem I have is that the compositor goes to standby after the idle-time even-though the video is playing.

Is there anyway to tell the compositor that application is active and it should not go to standby?

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't specify which compositor you are using. Assuming you are using weston compositor there is a api weston_compositor_wake(compositor) which will emit wake up signal if compositor goes to sleep mode. If you are using some other compositor please check analogous signal which serves the same purpose.